# rvm install on Mac OSX 10.8.4 gives 'Error running 'requirements_smf_lib_install libtool'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm

Trying to `rvm install ruby-1.9.3-head` got the following errors. I thought I installed Railsinstaller & XCode commandline tools, and these packages like libtool should install by default. What steps am I missing here?

```
Checking requirements for smf.
Installing requirements for smf.
songserm password required for 'sm get head': 
Updating system.

.
Installing required package: libtool..........................
Error running 'requirements_smf_lib_install libtool',
please read /usr/local/rvm/log/1382253809_ruby-1.9.3-head/package_install_libtool.log
Failed installation package: libtool of: libtool, gdbm.
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

The content of the log file is this:
/usr/local/rvm/log/1382253809_ruby-1.9.3-head/package_install_libtool.log

```
[2013-10-20 14:27:12] requirements_smf_lib_install
requirements_smf_lib_install ()
{
    typeset -a __smf_install_command;
    requirements_smf_lib_install_command "$@";
    rvm_debug "__smf_install_command: ${__smf_install_command[*]};";
    "${__smf_install_command[@]}" || {
        typeset ret=$?;
        rvm_warn "There were package installation errors with SM Framework, make sure to read the log.
If you see this on OSX, then you might want to try macports (http://www.macports.org/) or homebrew (http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/) and tell RVM to use them by running:

    rvm autolibs macports #OR
    rvm autolibs homebrew

You can get help using IRC: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm";
        return $ret
    };
    shift
}
current path: /Users/songserm/Dropbox/projects
command(2): requirements_smf_lib_install libtool
  [ ] libtool 2.4.2 ~ dependencies... ^M                                             ^M  [^[[32m✔^[[0m] libtool 2.4.2 ~ dependencies
  [ ] libtool 2.4.2 ~ fetch... curl: (9) Server denied you to change to the given directory
^M                                             ^M  [^[[32m✔^[[0m] libtool 2.4.2 ~ fetch

FAIL(paths): Path '/opt/sm/src/libtool-2.4.2' does not exist.

   +#   source file                                                    # function()
===========================================================================================
vi +330 /opt/sm/core/sm/shell/log/functions                            # __sm.log.fail
vi +32  /opt/sm/core/internal/shell/paths/functions                    # __sm.paths.enter
vi +144 /opt/sm/core/api/shell/paths/functions                         # paths
vi +54  /opt/sm/core/internal/shell/package/strategies/gnu/functions   # __sm.package.gnu.install
vi +15  /opt/sm/core/internal/shell/package/functions                  # __sm.package.install
vi +143 /opt/sm/core/api/shell/package/functions                       # package
vi +403 /opt/sm/core/sm/shell/log/functions                            # __sm.actions.call
vi +178 /opt/sm/core/internal/shell/extensions/execution/functions     # __sm.extension.run
vi +151 /opt/sm/core/sm/shell/core/initialize                          # /opt/sm/core/sm/shell/core/initialize
vi +41  /opt/sm/bin/sm                                                 # /opt/sm/bin/sm
===========================================================================================
There were package installation errors with SM Framework, make sure to read the log.
If you see this on OSX, then you might want to try macports (http://www.macports.org/) or homebrew (http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/) and tell RVM to use them by running:

    rvm autolibs macports #OR
    rvm autolibs homebrew

You can get help using IRC: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm
```

Comment: i guess i got the same error some time back and after wasting a lot of time i could'nt fix it directly , so i moved to homebrew for help. For me this solved the problem:

1) Install homebrew ( http://brew.sh/ )

2) tell rvm to use homebrew `rvm autolibs homebrew`

3) OPen a new tab and repeat the process of installing ruby via rvm.

This will make rvm to use homebrew to install required libraries.
I will suggest giving homebrew a try , as going forward you are going to get these lib dependency errors a lot.Let me know if that works for you or what finally worked for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug somewhere on the way, please report it to https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

Also as SM Framework is mostly used to build binaries for RVM you might want to try with Homebrew instead:

```
rvm get stable
rvm autolibs homebrew
rvm install 1.9.3-head
```

Please note that `1.9.3-head` means latest development code from `1_9_3` branch - not the latest  released patch level, to get the latest patchlevel use:

```
rvm get stable
rvm install 1.9.3
```

Comment: After I upgrade the XCode command line tool for Mountain Lion from September to October 2013 and follow your steps, it works. Noted that I used `rvmsudo rvm get stable` as mentioned in https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2301

Comment: it is sometimes needed, but not always

Answer (score 0):

Try this way without Homebrew:

INSTALL

```
# install RVM with --autolibs
$ curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby --autolibs=enabled --auto-dotfiles
```

OR

```
# update RVM with --autolibs
$ rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles --autolibs=enabled
```

THEN

```
# Restart terminal and check if everything is OK typing 
$ type rvm | head -1
# The answer should by "RVM is a function"

# Now install Ruby 1.9.3 specifying separate install dir and setting this version to default
$ rvm install 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr --verify-downloads 1
$ rvm use 1.9.3 --default

#You can switch between 'system' and 'default' ruby:
$ rvm default
$ rvm use system

# Check active ruby version
$ ruby -v
```